# Handling mobile images in responsive theme

Tags: 7, media

Sorry for the open-handed nature of the question, but I don't know where else to get an answer to this. I'm deciding whether or not go full-force into a responsive Drupal 7 theme, probably the Omega framework.

One issue that keeps nagging at me is that the mobile devices have to download all the large images (not to mention everything else...).

Is there an easy way to serve up smaller images for mobile devices?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many modules to handle responsive images, including;

1. [Responsive Images](http://drupal.org/project/responsive_images)
2. [Client-side adaptive image](http://drupal.org/project/cs_adaptive_image)
3. [Adaptive Image Styles (ais)](http://drupal.org/project/adaptive_image)
4. [Adaptive Image](http://drupal.org/project/adaptive_image)
5. [Borealis](http://drupal.org/project/borealis)

Comment: Great, I'll try some of these out!

Comment: The one that I got working properly, with support for Reverse Proxys was Client-Side Adaptive Image. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use different `imagecache` presets immediately comes to mind, eg, a set of them for the main, desktop theme, and another parallel set that creates smaller versions for the mobile theme, or if in the same theme, sets that toggle based upon the user agent of the user's browser.

Comment: Interesting. What is the best way to call the preset on each theme? Like, large for desktop, and thumbnail for mobile?

Comment: Off the cuff I was thinking inside the node templates, before displaying/rendering an image, check the user agent, and if mobile, display them one way, otherwise, display them another.  Probably lots of work, but also precise.

Answer (score 0):

I had been searching for a proper way to get adaptive images. Finally Client-Side Adaptive Image worked. You just have to make a few image styles. Then if you select image formatter as adaptive image then you can assign an image style for every breakpoint. You can even configure the no. of break points you want. Great module! Great Solution!