# Which module for responsive images without Apache?

Tags: 7, media, theming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling Mobile Images in Responsive Drupal 7 Theme](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19397/handling-mobile-images-in-responsive-drupal-7-theme)

I'm searching a good module to manage responsive images.

My site is build with [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) theme and the site will be published on a server that doesn't use Apache, so I can use modules that use .htaccess.

Which module do you suggest for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use these modules. also suggest to use Adaptive theme.

http://drupal.org/project/responsive_images 
http://drupal.org/project/resp_img

Comment: Why do you suggest adaptive theme? I've tried it, I prefer Omega :)

Comment: i just suggest for responsive as substitute of Omega...