# Image Responsive Carousel like image Gallery

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

I have created a view of images and I want to display those images in a carousel like display but that needs to be responsive. I came across a jquery plugin for this called "elastislide" but cannot properly figure out how to use it with drupal views I have followed the example [here](http://ucfstest.uc.edu/drupalteam/node/602), but nothing is working as such.

Comment: **Possible Duplicate**
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19397/handling-mobile-images-in-responsive-drupal-7-theme

Comment: The issue you mentioned is about how to make image responsive. What I need to know is how to make a responsive carousel just like this http://tympanus.net/Development/Elastislide/index.html

Comment: i have applied this and it works for me. plz check your configs (CSS and JS) files

Comment: I have created a list template for my view and added the id carousel and class elastislide-list to it and then placed the js code in my custom js file. I have also included all required js and css files but that doesn't seem to work at all I don't know if I have missed any configuration or not configured it properly

Comment: Make sure your js has no conflict.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fairly simple responsive carousel in views I would recommend checking out [Flexslider](https://drupal.org/project/flexslider) - it's pretty simple to setup and does everything you want I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Nivoslider , Viewslideshow` module.And for responsive you may need to do the css using `mediaquery` in `style.css`